# What happens when there are no actions for parent process during fork() processes?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, child-process

I have the following example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (){
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int)getpid());
    int rc = fork();

    if(rc < 0){ //fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);

    } else if (rc == 0) { //child new process
        printf("hello, i am child (pid:%d)\n", (int)getpid());
        char *myargs[3];
        myargs[0] = strdup("wc"); //program: "wc" (word count)
        myargs[1] = strdup("p3.c"); //argument: file to count
        myargs[2] = NULL; //marks end of array
        execvp(myargs[0],myargs); //runs word count
        printf("this shouldn't print out");

    } else {//parent process
        // int wc = wait(NULL);
        // printf("hello, i am parent of %d (wc: %d) (pid: %d)\n", rc, wc, (int) getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I have commented out the else statement (the arguments or the actions of the parent process. I was wondering what would happen, or would the outputs remain the same if the parent process does not have to wait for the child process? If so, why?

I was thinking, since the child process is its own independent process from the parent, the output would remain the same but is that the only reason why?

Some pointers would be nice, thanks!

Comment: The parent process would continue to the `return 0` and exit, leaving the child process an orphan.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So the parent process would terminate before the child process is done executing execvp, the word count?

Comment: Exactly when the parent process would terminate in relation to the child process is indeterminate, but it will most likely terminate before the `wc` program has finished. Oh and since processes are independent the child process will continue to run even though the parent terminates.

Comment: And since it is an independent process, the output to the word count program will remain the same even if the parent process terminates first right? I just want to make sure I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!   Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to what header files your actual code includes?

Comment: the returned type from `fork()` is a `pid_t`, which is not necessarily a `int`

Comment: the parent process should be calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` otherwise the parent will immediately exit, leaving the child process as a zombie.  The only way to get rid of zombie processes is to reboot the computer.

Comment: after this line: `execvp(myargs[0],myargs);` the next line should be: `perror( "execvp failed" );  then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling `strdup()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  names like `wc` and `rc` are meaningless, even in the current context  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: @user3629249 Your comment about zombies contains three factual errors. 1. It's fine for a parent process to not wait for a child. That's how daemons are spawned, among other things. 2. It will not make the child a zombie, that's not what a zombie is. In fact, parent process exiting is the easiest way to get rid of zombie processes. 3. zombie processes are cleaned up just fine on every system I'm aware of and there's no rebooting needed.

Comment: @user3629249 I have included the header files, and this code is an example code from my textbook I was trying to understand.

Comment: Note also that `fork()` returns `pid_t`, and *not* `int`.  You'll be in for a surprise should `pid_t` not fit into an `int` - and there's no guarantee that it will, which is why it was created in the first place.

Comment: @Art,  A zombie process is one that has no parent.  (you do know that there is a process chain that extends all the way back to the (in linux) `init()` process)  When the parent process exits, the chain is broken.  The (still running) child process is now a zombie.

Comment: @user3629249 That's not what a zombie is. I do know how processes work since I've actually worked on processes management in a real operating system. Including actually creating zombies. And reaping them.

Answer (score 2):

This can be understood in two contexts.

1. Execution time of parent < execution time of child
2. Execution time of parent > execution time of child

In case 1, the parent process exits before the child and hence, the init process (pid 1) becomes the parent of the child; child process continues execution.

Normally, a child process (resources of child process) cannot be released until the parent process completes. In case 2, the child process is released only after the completion of parent process; till that time the child process becomes a zombie (defunct in `ps -al` command).

In this particular context, when the parent process has nothing to execute, the **execution time of child > execution time of parent**, which is nothing but **execution time of parent < execution time of child**. This is case 1. Hence, the parent process exits and init process becomes the parent of the child process.